# Sorting multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have two numpy arrays in the same shape.

```
np.array_one = ([[1,4],[3,1]])
np.array_two = ([['A','B'],['C','D']])
```

I can sort multiple lists in python using zip, is there an equivalent for numpy arrays? So, I'd like to sort one list and then get the following list to sort in exactly the same way.

```
np.sort(array_one, array_two)
```

I'd like to produce the following equivalent:

```
array_one = ([[1,1],[3,4]])
array_two = ([['A','D'],['C','B']])
```

Comment: Sorting an array means changing the order of its elements, not *changing* those elements.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why this is not a sort? Especially since the solution (confirmed) uses a sort algorithm.

Comment: Would you say that sorting is equivalent to comparing, since one uses comparisons to do sorting?

Comment: Well that argument is a tautology and it still doesn't explain why you would go around down voting a question that is self evidently correctly labelled.

Comment: I'll sidestep the issue of tautology, I'm still (genuinely) trying to understand why this isn't a sort? As an input, I've got four elements in two rows in a numpy array, as an output I have the same four elements in two rows in a numpy array, but those elements are in a different order. Are you saying that if it had been a single row array (1x4) it would have been a sort, but because its split over two rows and I'm changing the items in what are effectively sub-lists, that it is not a sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argsort`; apply `argsort` on *array_one* and get the index that sorts the array which can then be applied to `array_two` to sort it (in the sense of *array_one*):

```
array_one = np.array([[1,4],[3,1]])
array_two = np.array([['A','B'],['C','D']])

array_two.ravel()[array_one.argsort(axis=None).reshape(array_one.shape)]

#array([['A', 'D'],
#       ['C', 'B']], 
#      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you.